# Does Urban Airship support all the features of Blackberry Push Plus?

Tags: blackberry, push-notification, urbanairship.com, blackberry-push

My team needs to send a push notification to BlackBerry devices and know (as soon as possible) whether the push notification got to the app. The BlackBerry Push Plus (as opposed to the BlackBerry Push Essentials) gives us this capability. We now are looking to develop this, but we found out about this company that has support for BlackBerry, iPhone and Android push notifications: Urban Airship. While it's clear that we can send the Push notifications to the BB device using their service, what's not clear is whether there's a way for us to be notified whether the push notification did reach the BlackBerry app.

Answer (score 1):

Urban Airship doesn't currently support the return receipt functionality that BlackBerry Push Plus provides.

You're correct that Urban Airship does support the basic push functionality across the various BlackBerry Push services.

*(I work for Urban Airship, feel free to contact us with more specific feedback and details on your use-case if you'd like.)*